# How do I disable 'modern login items'?

Tags: macos

Note to moderators: this is not a login item. This is not a LaunchAgent. Please stop marking this as a duplicate. Thank you.

Apple has seemingly given 3rd party app developers more control over my OS than me, the user and owner of this computer. Can someone please explain how to disable 'modern login items'? The only work-around I know of currently is to edit the app bundle which did work with one app but I cannot guarantee will work with others, plus Apple will probably get POed that users have control over their Macs and close this loophole.

Comment: Let’s fix your other post. Editing it to show clearly how it’s not the same situation helps all the moderators vote to reopen a closed post. This can take a day or three so please be patient.

Comment: Ok. Your other question is now in the review queue for all the senior users to see to vote for a reopen.